# Rails - Change Image Directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory

I've developed a simple app to display images in a series of subdirectories based on querystring input. (I more or less built my own Rails version of 360Works SuperContainer, for FileMaker.) I have copied a few test directories into `public/images` and everything seems to be working just great, but this app needs to operate over upwards of 60gb of images, and putting them all into the `public/images` folder isn't going to really be feasible.

Other than hard-coding the path into my model, how can I set a configuration option to specify a different default directory for the `images` folder?

Comment: what about symlinking (ln -s) the public/images to another filesystem path

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the asset_host field :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#M001688